# Python3: сравнение двух сложных словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict, compare

Имею сложности со сравнением двух словарей - структура примерно вот такая:

```
{
    "data": {
        "blob": {
            "pool": {},
            "positions": {
                "1": {
                    "education": [],
                    "work": [
                        {
                            "company": "test",
                            "name": "Alex",
                            "source": "html"
                        }
                    ],
                    "is_real": false,
                    "orig": {},
                    "old": {}
                },
                "2": {
                    "education": [],
                    "work": [
                        {
                            "company": "line",
                            "name": "Ivan",
                            "source": "html"
                        },
                        {
                            "company": "line2",
                            "name": "Max",
                            "source": "excel"
                        }
                    ],
                    "is_real": false,
                    "orig": {},
                    "old": {}
                }
            },
            "num": "78"
        },
        "type": "first",
        "id": 12,
        "task_id": 1
    },
    "result": "success"
}
```

Второй словарь выглядит так же, за исключением поля

```
/data/blob/positions/2/work/name
```

только вместо Max - Kirill.

Каким образом я могу сравнить эти словари, получив как результат ключ с измененным значением?

Я пробовал отсортировать оба словаря через OrderedDict, и сравнивать по ключам, каждый раз спускаясь на уровень ниже, однако мое сравнение уходило в ключ, где все значения совпадают.
Изучение похожих решений приводило к результату "словари отличаются полем 'data' (корневым элементом)" (изза сложной вложенности словаря).

Хотелось бы получить более точное указание ключа и его значения, как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265939/comparing-python-dictionaries-and-nested-dictionaries

Comment: @MaxU - прошу подсказать решение с элегантным возвращением пути-ключа, собираемого в рекурсивном решении. Не так как у меня с глобальной переменной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного исправленный из предложенного @MaxU ответа вариант решения:

```
def findDiff(d1, d2, path=""):
global res_path
for k in d1.keys():
    if not  k in d2.keys():
        print (path, ":")
        print (k + " as key not in d2", "\n")
    else:
        if type(d1[k]) is dict:
            path = k if not path else path + "\\" + k
            findDiff(d1[k],d2[k], path)
        else:
            if d1[k] != d2[k]:
                print (path, ":")
                print (" - ", k," : ", d1[k])
                print (" + ", k," : ", d2[k] )
                res_path = path

res_path = ''  
print ("comparing d1 to d2:")
findDiff(d1,d2)
print ("Искомый ключ:",res_path)
print ("comparing d2 to d1:")
findDiff(d2,d1)
```

подправил на Python версии 3+.
Также для возвращения искомого ключа "path" добавил глобальную переменную `res_path` для результата.
Был бы признателен @MaxU за дальнейшее улучшение решения с возвратом значения.

Comment: мне больше понравился [второй ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35065035/5741205), который как раз более правильно использует работу с рекурсивной функцией и возвращаемым значением.