# Сравнение двух словарей

Tags: python, python-2.x

Есть два массива данных собраных с разных linux систем и баз данных

1. data_db
2. data_linux

Нужно найти совпадения, и выполнить простое арифметическое действие, то есть, если `key` из `data_db` и `key` из `data_linux` совпадают, то:

```
key,value(data_db) - key,value(data_linux) = result
```

Пробовал искать совпадения таким образом:

```
def compare_dict():
    data_db_keys = set(data_db.keys())
    data_linux_keys = set(data_linux.keys())
    match = data_db_keys.intersection(data_linux_keys)
    print(match)
```

Но не могу понять, как быть с арифметикой. Пробовал делать таким способом:

```
def compare_dict():
    data_db_keys = set(data_db.keys())
    data_linux_keys = set(data_linux.keys())
    if data_db_keys.intersection(data_linux_keys):
       result = data_db_keys.value() - data_linux_keys.value()
```

Но тут сбился с толку, так как типы данных не `int` и тд, и выглядит довольно глупо и не логично. `value` всегда цифры, а если туда попадает не цифра, то записываю 0.

Кто может подсказать идею, как решить такую задачу?

---

PS Из комментария:
Есть массив номер1: `{server1 : 55.... }`, масив номер2: `{server1 : 38...}`

Ищу совпадение по ключам `server1 == server1`, если есть совпадение то:

```
server1.value(массив1) - server1.value(массив2) = result
```

Comment: можете привести в вопросе пример входных данных и то, что хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: могу, есть массив номер1: {server1 : 55....  } масив номер2: {server1 : 38...},  ищу совпадение по ключам server1 == server1, если есть совпадение то server1.value(массив1) - server1.value(массив2) = result

Comment: Используйте кнопку ["править"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/941271/edit) под вопросом, чтобы отредактировать вопрос. Код в комментариях - нечитабельный...

Answer (score 2):

Ну вы почти все сделали, вам осталось только посчитать. Для этого можно брать имена ключей из вашего сета, состоящего из общих ключей, вытягивать из словарей значения по этим ключам и считать разницу.

Входные данные взял из ответа MaxU

```
d1 = dict(server1 = 55, server2 = 33, server3 = 44)
d2 = dict(server1 = 38, server3 = 99, server4 = 10)

def compare_dict():
    data_db_keys = set(d1.keys())
    data_linux_keys = set(d2.keys())

    common_keys = data_db_keys.intersection(data_linux_keys)

    if common_keys:
        # Подсчет значений и создание словаря
        return {k: d1[k] - d2[k] for k in common_keys}


compare_dict()
# Результат: {'server1': 17, 'server3': -55}
```

Конструкция `{k: d1[k] - d2[k] for k in common_keys}` называется `dict comprehension`. Это компактный способ создания словарей, списков, кортежей. Результат будет тот же самый, что и при выполнении этого кода:

```
result = {}

for k in common_keys:
    result[k] = d1[k] - d2[k]
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение с использованием модуля [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd  #  pip install pandas
```

сначала создадим из словарей Pandas Series:

```
In [78]: d1 = dict(server1=55,server2=33,server3=44)

In [79]: d2 = dict(server1=38,server3=99,server4=10)

In [80]: s1 = pd.Series(d1)

In [81]: s2 = pd.Series(d2)

In [82]: s1
Out[82]:
server1    55
server2    33
server3    44
dtype: int64

In [83]: s2
Out[83]:
server1    38
server3    99
server4    10
dtype: int64
```

теперь можно объединить DataFrame'ы созданные из Series по значениям индекса и воспользоваться внутренней арифметикой:

```
In [84]: s1.to_frame('s1').join(s2.to_frame('s2')).eval("s1 - s2")
Out[84]:
server1    17.0
server2     NaN
server3   -55.0
dtype: float64
```

избавляемся от `NaN` (Not a Number):

```
In [85]: s1.to_frame('s1').join(s2.to_frame('s2')).eval("s1 - s2").dropna()
Out[85]:
server1    17.0
server3   -55.0
dtype: float64
```

результат в виде словаря:

```
In [86]: s1.to_frame('s1').join(s2.to_frame('s2')).eval("s1 - s2").dropna().to_dict()
Out[86]: {'server1': 17.0, 'server3': -55.0}
```

Comment: не могу использовать Pandas, нашел ваше решение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/889576/python3-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9?rq=1

Comment: возможно смогу решить таким способом, спасибо за подсказку